# estoy tratando ecceder a una coleccion en mongo usando express - nodejs, pero enves de eso me crea una coleccion con un nombre similar

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, colecciones

[image: imagen del codigo]
imagen del codigo para que se tenga un aidea mas clara de lo que estoy haciendo

Comment: En lugar de una imagen, coloca código, te ayudamos a darle formato. Por cierto, un título tiene la idea general, en el cuerpo del mensaje va la descripción, un buen título y una buena descripción aumenta la chance de obtener una respuesta, para incrementar aún más esa chance, aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] recuerda hacer el [tour] y revisar [ask]. A que te refieres con que "me crea una coleccion con nombre similar"? estás usando mongoose?